# How can I list all users with their username and group-name? in UNIX systems

Tags: linux, users

How can I list all users with their username and group-name in UNIX systems?

I want to take report form `/etc/passwd` file and `/etc/group` file

In passwd file, I'll get only GIDS but I also want to get group-name from `/etc/group`, and it should come in one report like I want below mention Fotomat

User neme ( user ID) , Group name ,

Comment: Accounts may exist outside of /etc/passwd...

Comment: I echo what Jeff is saying. Accounts may exist out of /etc/passwd...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With single **`awk`** command:

```
awk -F':' 'NR==FNR{ a[$3]=$1; next }{ print $1", "a[$4] }' /etc/group /etc/passwd
```

- `-F':'` - field separator
- `NR==FNR{ a[$3]=$1; next }` - processing the 1st input file (i.e. `/etc/group`):

  - `a[$3]=$1` - capture *group name* `$1` using *group identifier* `$3` as array `a` key
  - `next` - jump to next record
- `{ print $1", "a[$4] }` - action for the 2nd input file (i.e. `/etc/passwd`):

  - `$1` - the 1st field; indicating *user name*
  - `a[$4]` - get *group name* by group id (presented by field `$4`)

Comment: very good, thanks for explaining this +1

Comment: @DeclanGallagher, you're welcome

Comment: its working fine with Red hat and AIX fine , but i am trying to do same in the SUNOS i am getting some different format its giving line by line , report i want to get like first Group , name  but in sunos its giving  one by one  @RomanPerekhrest

Answer (score 0):

The following does a relational JOIN on the two files on the GID and outputs the username and group name with a `:` in-between:

```
join -t : -1 4 -2 3 -o 1.1,2.1 \
    <( sort -t : -k4,4 /etc/passwd ) \
    <( sort -t : -k3,3 /etc/group )
```

The GID is in column 4 in the `passwd` file and in column 3 in the `group` file.

With `-1` and `-2` we specify what the join field is in the two input files and with `-o` we specify what fields we want to output from each file (the first field of each file).

The sorting of each file on the join field in necessary for `join` to work.

To get this in the *exact* format requested, just pipe it though `sed 's/:/, /'` which replaces the colons with comma and space.